# How to automate a test in Oracle without using Java?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have a stored procedure that needs to be run to grab a daily sum of values (based off day) in the database. Is there an automated approach to do this comparison within Oracle? I was looking around online and couldn't find any examples...

The script I will run to execute the Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
execute sum_daily;
```

Some Sample Data is as follows:

```
Value_ID       Value_Tx         Value_Type
1              5                A
2              2                A 
3              7                B
4              5                C
5              3                C
6              1                D
7              7                F
```

Expected Value (Inserted by the Stored Procedure):

```
Sum            Value_Type
14               A | B
8                 C
1                 D
7                 F
```

Is there a way I can test ('automatically' via a script (PL-SQL?)) whether or not the expected values match up with the results inserted by the stored procedure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You definitely can't do it with "T-SQL" as that is specific to Microsoft SQL Server and not supported by Oracle

Comment: It looks like you are searching for unit test framework http://utplsql.org/utPLSQL/latest/ and the same for `T-SQL`: http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/assertions/assertequalstable/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry i meant 'PL-SQL'

Comment: @lad2025 thanks! going to see if i can apply this in PL-SQL so i can use it in oracle!